# getWidth() didnt give right panel width when called

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am working on a Java `JFrame` object and whenever I called the value of my `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`, it is always returning more than the value I set for my Panel using the `setPreferredSize()` function.

Can someone tell me why? Form instance if I declare my Panel to `this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,400));`

I do get value 520, and 462 whenever I call the `getWidth()`, and `getHeight()` respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The panel is laying inside the `JFrame` that has a border and a title bar. These pieces increase the size of the `JFrame` and their size depends on Look and Feel and operating system.

Comment: Also, the preferred, minimum & maximum sizes are only suggestions that the layout managers **MIGHT* use